# Distinguishing deletions from normal text

Tags: office-js

When track changes are shown in line, and you ask for a paragraphs text, the deleted text is reported as part of the paragraph with no way to tell that it's been deleted.  If the user has their track changes to show in balloons (or not shown) then the text is not reported.  This is a real problem especially since we can't currently tell what view state the document is in.

Is there something i'm missing here in this regard?  how can you tell when text is deleted and only shown due to track changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stewart: yeah this is a known issue, currently there is no way in the API to know if the user is in review mode. Something we are planning to add in the future, but with a non-deterministic date.

one potential workaround, is that you get the OOXXML of the paragraph  or the range and sniff it to see if there are any review marks, have you tried that?

also make sure to add/vote this in our uservoice channel.  thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately that would only sorta work.  You'd know the track changes were there but since the behavior varies based on balloon versus inline that it's not reliable.  Sniffing for the balloon style doesn't seem like a great option. 

There is a very similar behavior with hidden text and show hide being toggled.